# Where to ask a question about future version numbers of Clang vs. Apple Clang?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask where to ask a question like this:

> I'm just curious if there are any known plans about what happens when the LLVM version numbers eventually catch up to Apple's ridiculous version numbers.  It's close if not has already happened.

Does such a question belong anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, or should I reach out to the mailing lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess a mailing list of the project is your best bet. There are the people organizing the project and those capable of actually sharing their release roadmap.

On Stack Overflow such a question doesn't fit well. It is open-ended and very open to speculation. And since such roadmaps can change very often, the answer you receive might become obsolete the moment it was posted.

Comment: +1, I dont know if all SE site got it, but on SF we got the close reason *primarily opinion-based* that directly fit your answer

Comment: Understood, I'll reach out to the mailing lists.  Thanks for being gentle :)